# TortoiseSVN - how to merge branch into trunk?

Tags: merge, tortoisesvn

I've been using TortoiseSVN for a while, but have never really had to branch/merge. Our practice has been just to commit to the trunk (from our development server), and update from the trunk (on our production server).

Recently though, I've made it my mission to master branching and merging. Branching is pretty easy, but merging has been giving me some trouble; conceptually merging isn't hard to grasp, but something's getting lost in the actual execution.

As a simple branching/merging exercise, I started with the trunk, which only has a page of text that reads "This is the trunk before any changes". I changed that line to read "This is code from project A," (WITHOUT committing to the trunk), then created a branch from my working copy, and opted to keep my working copy on the trunk instead of switching to that new branch. So I've created a branch with my "Project A" code, but my working copy is still on the trunk, where it reads "This is the trunk before any changes". Then I created a branch for "Project B" by repeating that process with a line that reads "This is code from project B".

So I end up with my working copy on the trunk, where it reads "This is the trunk before any changes". And I have my two separate branches for Project A and Project B, both of which I want to merge into the trunk, one at a time. The idea is to simulate a situation where I've completed work on two different projects, but I'm waiting for them both to be approved for deployment to production, and I don't know which one will be approved first. Or if either will even be approved before I need to start development on a Project C.

Now I'm pretending that project A has been approved, so I'm trying to merge the Project A branch with the trunk. I'm expecting to start the merge, get a message saying there's a conflict, and then be able to edit the conflict so that the project A line of text replaces the trunk line of text on the merged file, and then be able to mark that conflict as resolved. (And I realize I could include both lines in the merged file, one on top of the other, if I wanted to). So I expect that after I merge, the trunk will have a line reading "This is code from Project A", and the line reading "This is the trunk before any changes" will have been removed.

But that hasn't been working as I expect. From the trunk, I'm right-clicking on the file, selecting "merge", and in the dialog I choose to "Merge 2 different trees". I select the trunk url for the "from", and the project A branch url for the "to". Then I merge, but no conflicts are indicated, and nothing on the trunk or the project A branch changes. My working copy remains on the trunk, and the file still has only 1 line of text, "This is the trunk before any changes".

I'm reviewing the info at https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html, and I'm not certain where I'm getting it wrong. Any help's appreciated.

Comment: This should work just fine. Are you sure, you have commited all changes to trunk and all other branches? You don't have any changes in your local copy? Maybe try merge a range of revisions. I'm using it all the time. Select your trunk -> Merge -> Merge a range of revisions, in Url to merge select your branch, in Revisions range to merge select all revisions from branch -> Next -> Merge, review your local changes and then commit.

Comment: Thanks, I see what's happening. Trunk and both branches are committed. When I merge the project A branch and the trunk, it doesn't treat the 2 different lines as a conflict, which is what I was expecting. The line reading "This is code from Project A" overwrites the line reading "This is the trunk before any changes". I commit that to trunk, then I merge trunk with the Project B branch, and again there's no conflict. The line reading "This is code from Project B" overwrites the line reading "this is code from Project A". So I just need to research how to include both lines in the merged file.

Comment: Okay, to include both lines, it looks like I can't really do that during the merge. I can do it, however, during the post-merge commit. I right-clk on the file and choose "SVN Commit", dbl-clk on the filename to see what's changing, and then I can copy/paste the replaced code to my working copy and save (I'm using WinMerge as my compare tool). Now I commit to the trunk, and as I want there are 2 lines of code. One reads "This is code from Project A", and one reads "This is code from Project B". Still curious why the diff isn't picked up as a conflict during merge, though.

Comment: Because there is no conflict at all. This is just regular change in a file. If you want to see a conflict, create a new branch, then make changes in this file in both branch and trunk; then try to merge it.